# Why are people using the space-less 'funcname"string"' style in Lua?

Tags: coding-style, lua

In Lua, if a function accepts a single argument which is a string literal, we can omit the parentheses.

What I'm curious about is why many people, whom I regard as very proficient in Lua, aren't typing a space in between. E.g., they do:

```
local re = require're'
s = f:read'*a'
```

instead of:

```
local re = require 're'
s = f:read '*a'
```

Why is that?

Comment: This is primarily opinion-based...

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you can do this with tables too. For example, `type{}` will be `table`.

Comment: @RyanStein, and you can mix the two as in `host "myhost" { ip="0.0.0.0" }`.

Comment: @lhf: Obviously this is opinion-based. What I'm curious about is "where" this style comes from. I feel there's room for this question (which haven't yet been answered), as this style is used by prominent users of Lua, and I don't quite understand why people vote for closing it. I want to stress that I'm not judgmental: I wasn't criticizing this style; I merely want to know its origin.

Answer (score 1):

Since Lua 2.1 (1995) it is possible to write `f{}` instead of `f({})` to cater for data files like BibTeX.

Since Lua 3.1 (1998) it is possible to write `f"hello"` instead of `f("hello")` to cater for domain specific languages and more natural config files such as `host "myhost"`. It also suits expressions such as `require"re"`, which feels like `require` is a keyword, instead of a function.

These two forms can be combined, for even more natural expressions such as `host "myhost" { ip="0.0.0.0" }`.

So, to try to answer your question, these forms are motivated by clarity and expressiveness, though it also caters for laziness.

Comment: Could you please explain why you write `f"hello"` instead of `f "hello"`? *That* has been my question.

Comment: @NiccoloM., oh, that is a question of style.

Answer (score 1):

With a monospaced font `require're'` is readable enough and looks good.
In syntax highlighting environments `require` and `'re'` will have different colors.
So, there is absolutely no need for additional space.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is made to be under user control fully, You can put as many spaces as you want, or use `"string"` instead of `'string'`, Every people can customize their lua coding, It's not like C/C++ that you have to type the arg only in one style, You can use your custom way, the way you like to. Lua doesn't require you to use only one space or just not use any space. Lua reads codes by searching your args, Doesn't matter how many spaces you enter it just searches for your keyword with as many spaces as it might have. That makes lua easy to code after coding some python or C++, So you don't have to change the way you program for just moving into lua. These are almost any ways you can use your code:

```
local re = require're'
s = f:read'*a'

local re = require('re')
s = f:read('*a')

local re = require('re');
s = f:read('*a');

local re = require 're'
s = f:read '*a'

local re = require"re"
s = f:read "*a"

local re = require("re")
s = f:read("*a")

local re = require("re");
s = f:read("*a");

local re = require    ("re");
s = f:read     ('*a");
```

That basically means adding spaces, removing braces or adding semicolon wouldn't affect the code. also a lua string is `"` or `'`. New lines also wouldn't affect the code, here's an example:

```
print"aaa"print"aac"print"aab"
```

But the best is make your code readable, It makes it easier for you to fix and bug-fix them. Adding no new lines makes it impossible to debug an error, It just returns an error on line #1 which is the whole code.

Comment: I know all this. I didn't ask **how** are people able to do this but **why** are they using this style. Note that my question is tagged with "coding-style".